# Bash script if condition not working when called from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: bash, scripts, jenkins

The below is my Jenkins Pipeline stage

```
stage ('Import') {

            steps {
                sshagent([sshCredentials]) {
                    sh '''
                        #!/bin/bash
                        sh -x ETL_AUTOMATION/Scripts/export.sh
                    '''
```

Build output:-

```
[[ RMO_TST12 ==  ]]

ETL_AUTOMATION/Scripts/export.sh: 17: ETL_AUTOMATION/Scripts/export.sh: [[: not found
```

`if` condition in script:-

```
if [[ "$SOURCE_FOLDER" == "" ]]; then

    echo "SOURCE_FOLDER not specified... exiting"
    exit 1
fi
```

I have mentioned `#!/bin/bash` in my script also.

Please help me, I am really stuck here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are running `sh -x ETL_AUTOMATION/Scripts/export.sh`. This means that `export.sh` is being run by `sh` and not `bash`. On Ubuntu, `sh` is a simple POSIX shell called `dash` and that doesn't support the `[[` construct, which is a `bash` thing. So just change your script so that it is launched with `bash` instead of `sh`. I don't know the Jenkins syntax at all, but I suspect you want one of these:

```
sshagent([sshCredentials]) {
    sh '''
        ETL_AUTOMATION/Scripts/export.sh
        '''
```

or, if your `export.sh` isn't executable:

```
sshagent([sshCredentials]) {
    sh '''
        bash ETL_AUTOMATION/Scripts/export.sh
        '''
```

Or, perhaps simply:

```
sshagent([sshCredentials]) {
    bash '''
        ETL_AUTOMATION/Scripts/export.sh
        '''
```

Alternatively, you can change `export.sh` so it doesn't use bash-only features:

```
if [ -z $SOURCE_FOLDER ]; then
    echo "SOURCE_FOLDER not specified... exiting"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: thank you man this worked :)